# unable to resolve identifier push_back

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-8

I have a small problem with C++ vector. 
In my .H file i have

```
class MyClass{ 
private:
    std::vector<myObject> test;
public:
    MyClass();
    add(myObject object);
}
```

In my .CPP file

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    std::vector<myObject> test;
}
MyClass::add(myObject object){
//here is the problem. Netbeans does even giving me quick cast this method i need to write it myself and it throws an error.
    test.push_back(object);
}
```

I am using NetBeans 8 and it says "Unable to resolve identfier push_back and I don't know why. I'm pretty new to C++ and done some research but it seems like I can't find the answer.
My goal is to have .H file and i initialize vector in .CPP and then i want to have separate function like add to push my objects to this class that contains a vector. Something like a list where you can add your objects.

Thank You for help.

EDIT:
And yes I include vector at the top.

EDIT:
Thats the code

```
   #include <vector>

class MyClass{ 
private:
    int a;
    std::vector<int> test;
public:
    MyClass();
    void add(int n);
};

MyClass::MyClass(){
}

void MyClass::add(int m){
//unable to resolve identifier push_back
    test.push_back(m);
}

int main() {

    MyClass a();
//request for member add in a which is of non class type
    a.add(1);


}
```

Comment: Not what you asked about, but the constructor creates an extra local vector called `test` and throws that away immediately. This is not the same as the class member `test`.

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with the code. Post a verifiable example.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. And is that the full error message?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], this code is far too incomplete to allow anything diagnosable.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add return type for `add` method.
Try this in H:

```
void add(myObject object);
```

And this in CPP:

```
void MyClass::add(myObject object){
```

Comment: Tried it already and it does not fix the problem. push_back is still not resolved.

Comment: @Matt [compiles flawlessly here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7367f47214815266).

Comment: Yes it compiles but copy and past it into netbeans and you will see my error. Its like i cant call push_back on vector.

Comment: You should add `;` at the end of H file after class definition as well.

Comment: When I want to use .add() method in main file it doesnt compile and gives main.cpp:24:7: error: request for member 'add' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'MyClass()' error.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {

    MyClass a();
//request for member add in a which is of non class type
    a.add(1);


}
```

> //request for member add in a which is of non class type

Because `a` is not a `MyClass` object. In order to make it one, you need to construct it like this:

`MyClass a{};`

or simply like this:

`MyClass a;`

Otherwise it is treated as function declaration. Here it is, compiled with no errors https://ideone.com/y7fQXo

Comment: Yes it fixed one problem thank you but i still cannot use push_back inside of a method. It compiles but it gives me an error that push_back cannot be resolved.I read online it might be with some netbeans bug but i dont know if thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your "full" code (which doesn't show the dividing line between `.h` and `.cpp`, but I'm taking you at your word that the code is complete), it's clear there is only one `#include`, at the top of the `.h` code. I'm assuming the `.cpp` code begins with the line `MyClass::MyClass(){`, which means it has no includes. Thus, it doesn't have *any* of the information from your header, and by extension, has none of the information from `<vector>`.

`#include <vector>` is needed in your `.h` (because you used `vector` in the class definition), but you *also* need to `#include "myclass.h"` (or whatever you named your header file) in `myclass.cpp` (or whatever you named the source file).

Without it, while the compiler is compiling the `.cpp` file, it's just stumbling in the dark. It has no definition for `MyClass` as a whole, and therefore has no idea `test` is a member of type `vector<int>`. Not knowing what `test` is (and for that matter, not knowing what a `vector<int>` is), it can't resolve any methods on it.

To make this work, you need to include your `.h` in your `.cpp` so the compiler has the declarations to interpret your method definitions. If your header is named `myclass.h`, add:

```
#include "myclass.h"
```

to the top of your `.cpp`. For good measure, it might also make sense to explicitly `#include <vector>` in the source file as well; yes, it will get it by side-effect via including the header, but it's largely harmless to double-include standard library headers (protected against double-inclusion via include guards), and it makes it clear what standard library components you're relying on (useful to maintainers).

Comment: Done it already. Question can be closed. I dont exactly remember what the solution was but i sorted it out ;)